# How do I escape a series of backslashes in a bash printf?

Tags: string, bash, escaping, backslash

The following script yielded an unexpected output:

```
printf "escaped slash: \\ \n"
printf "2 escaped slashes: \\\\ \n"
printf "3 escaped slashes: \\\\\\ \n"
printf "4 escaped slashes: \\\\\\\\ \n"
```

Run as a bash script under Ubuntu 14, I see:

```
escaped slash: \
2 escaped slashes: \ 
3 escaped slashes: \\ 
4 escaped slashes: \\
```

Err.. *what?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that `printf` `FORMAT` string is surrounded by double quotes, `printf` takes one additional level of expansion, compared to e.g. `echo` (both being shell builtin commands).

What you expect from `printf` can actually be achieved using single quotes:

```
printf '1 escaped slash:   \\ \n'
printf '2 escaped slashes: \\\\ \n'
printf '3 escaped slashes: \\\\\\ \n'
printf '4 escaped slashes: \\\\\\\\ \n'
```

outputs:

```
1 escaped slash:   \
2 escaped slashes: \\
3 escaped slashes: \\\
4 escaped slashes: \\\\
```

Comment: Note this works because you prevent `bash` from removing any backslashes before `printf` sees the argument.

Comment: @chepner: I agree. It seems the order of evaluation is: 1) `bash` expands the `FORMAT` string *(only if surrounded by double quotes!)*. 2) `printf` combines the `ARGUMENTS` and the `FORMAT` into one string. 3) The final string is expanded again (i.e. \\ becomes \ ). 4) The result is finally printed.

Comment: Close; `printf` only process the `FORMAT` before inserting the arguments; compare `printf '\n'` with `printf '%s' '\n'`.

Answer (score 6):

`printf` is a bash builtin. Look at `help printf`:

```
printf [-v var] format [arguments]
      Formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT.
```

You should pass the format and the argument. So add the format `"%s\n"` before the argument:

```
printf "%s\n" "escaped slash: \\"
printf "%s\n" "2 escaped slashes: \\\\"
printf "%s\n" "3 escaped slashes: \\\\\\"
printf "%s\n" "4 escaped slashes: \\\\\\\\"
```

Output:

```
escaped slash: \ 
2 escaped slashes: \\ 
3 escaped slashes: \\\ 
4 escaped slashes: \\\\
```

Comment: @Yuri G.: Thank you for your additional description.

Comment: Note this works because you avoid `printf` applying another round of interpretation of backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

An additional note on what Cyrus said:

If you quote the `printf`'s `ARGUMENT` with single quotes, you should save a lot of backslashes. For example,

```sh
printf "%s\n" 'escaped slash: \'
printf "%s\n" '2 escaped slashes: \\'
printf "%s\n" '3 escaped slashes: \\\'
printf "%s\n" '4 escaped slashes: \\\\'
```

outputs

```
1 escaped slash:   \
2 escaped slashes: \\
3 escaped slashes: \\\
4 escaped slashes: \\\\
```